# Cannot convert value of type FBSDKGraphRequestHandler

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2

I'm getting the following error when I try to make a data request using the Facebook SDK:

`Cannot convert value of type '(_,_,_) throws -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!'`

Here is the relevant code where the error is occurring. I found this in a tutorial but I think it worked with older versions of XCode. I'm using the latest version 7.2.1.

UPDATED

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender, email"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler ({ [weak self] connection, result, error in
            if error != nil {
                //onError()
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                    //get results

                    PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
                    PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]

                    try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()

                    let userId = result["id"] as! String

                    let facebookProfilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"

                    if let fbpicUrl = NSURL(string: facebookProfilePictureUrl) {

                        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbpicUrl) {

                            self.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data)

                            let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: data)!

                            PFUser.currentUser()?["image"] = imageFile

                            try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
                          }
                }
            }
        })
```

Thanks!

PICTURE (click on the image to make it larger)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzt6b.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are using the latest `FBSDK` in that the `completionHandler:` has been changed. See the below code:

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: param)
graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { [weak self] connection, result, error in
     if error != nil {
          //onError()
          print(error.description)
          return
     }else{

          let fbResult = result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
          //Do You rest of the code here
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your code doesn't generate errors until I try to add code to handle results. How can I do this? Once I added `else if let result = result` I got error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

I updated the code in my question. Thanks!!

Comment: @james Just remove this part of code `if let result = result` and keep `else` as it is and your code will work fine!

Comment: Updated the code again! Something is still wrong. Now I'm getting the original error again.  I must be doing something wrong here...

Comment: @james can you pls specify the error again? or just an upload a screenshot

Comment: @james also I hope you have one closing bracket extra at last

Comment: yes, I have one last bracket to close out the whole viewDidLoad function. I'll upload a screenshot now. Thanks!!

Comment: @james The problem is that `result` is coming in `NSDictionary` and without assigning or casting you can do that!

Comment: It still doesn't like the rest of the code. The errors are still there. I also can confirm that I am using the latest FB SDK's, last updated in January of this year. Any other ideas?

Comment: @james Just comment all your `Parse` code the just keep this line `print("FbResult \(fbResult)")`. If this line works means you have issues with the rest of the code and also try login with it!

Comment: Must be an issue with my Parse code. That works! Thank you very much. I'll have to rewrite the Parse code to work with the new SDK. Thanks again friend!

Comment: @james No problem. You can get the parse code on their official site.